# Decoding JSON data saved in a database column

Tags: javascript, json, django

When i parse the JSON data i have saved in my database directly in HTML i get some messed up chars and basically it looks encoded?

Here is a sample from the HTML file:

```
'{&quot;web_rendition&quot;:{&quot;@xmlns&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;content&quot;:
```

How do i encode this mess or load it into a JSON object?

View class:

```
    content = Cond.objects.get(pk=pk).con_con.con_chron
    context['new_content'] = content
    return context
```

My template:

```
<script>
content = "{{new_content}}";
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: There is a weird invisible character at the beginning of the string. Also, why are the quotation makes HTML encoded?

Comment: Felix, i dont have a clue. This string is parsed directly through a Django filter into the view. Maybe it requires to be serialized first?

Comment: use something like underscore/underscore_string and unescape the html before you parse _.unescapeHTML(content) and then JSON.parse the result.

Comment: You should show the template that's outputting that JS.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, the View class?

Comment: There we go, i think that should do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is happening in the template layer, you may need a 'safe' filter to keep it from getting encoded like this.

`content = "{% my_json_variable|safe %}"`

[safe filter in django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/templates/builtins/#safe)

Comment: That is very close, now its encoded correctly, but theres still the dot in the beginning. I have checked my database content and i cant find this dot in any rows.

Comment: Oh wait a minute. I actually found few rows that consist of `ďťż`, which apperantly is the marker. I need to filter this out somehow.

Comment: I ran through the shell and parsed the element from my database. In the very beginning i get a `u'\ufeff` char.